# How to transfer the data between 2 apps in same iOS device using different Bundle id

Tags: ios

Am having APP 1 and APP 2  ,App 1 having some user information like (Name,Age,DOB ) ,I will get data from APP 1 through APP 2 .

Case 1 : App 1 using different Bundle id from Developer account .APP 2 using different Bundle id from developer account.

Can you please give me some answer .

Comment: It is not possible in iOS to share data between two apps when the bundle identifier is different.

Comment: please go thought mohit answer he given clear explanation  that it is not possible and he given the apple privacy guidelines link

Comment: Apple is not allowed. Because apple having many security principles.

Answer (score 1):

Its not Possible in iOS.

**Privacy**

Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to information about how and where the data will be used.

***Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected.***

Apps may ask for date of birth (or use other age-gating mechanisms) only for the purpose of complying with applicable children's privacy statutes, but must include some useful functionality or entertainment value regardless of the user's age.

Apps that collect, transmit, or have the capability to share personal information (e.g. name, address, email, location, photos, videos, drawings, the ability to chat, other personal data, or persistent identifiers used in combination with any of the above) from a minor must comply with applicable children's privacy statutes, and must include a privacy policy.

Apps that include account registration or access a user’s existing account must include a privacy policy or they will be rejected.

Please go through this link [Apple Privacy guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/#privacy)

Answer (score 0):

Every App runs in it's own sandbox which is completely separated from the other apps on your device. You cannot save files in a shared space like you would on a PC.

If you want to transfer data between two apps you either have to use a webserver or try using iCloud (which is the webserver approach in the end)

Comment: Using  iCloud also having same Bundle iD Right? But my case we are using Different Bundle id from Different Developer Account ?

Comment: you can setup a shared container https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW14

Comment: One Quick Question : Share the same container in multiple apps, (Here Multiple app using Different Development Account Bundle ID Right ? )

Comment: In the Xcode target editor’s Summary pane, you can request access to as many iCloud containers as you need for your app. This feature is useful if you want multiple apps to share documents. For example, if you provide a free and paid version of your app, you might want users to retain access to their iCloud documents when they upgrade from the free version to the paid version. In such a scenario, configure both apps to write their data to the same iCloud container.  I think it is only for one developer though.

Comment: Is it is For One Developer account  ? not for Different  developer account Rite?